# How to notify the device that is doing the Voice-Call that the call is CONNECTED in Twilio Voice-SDK

Tags: android, twilio

I´m using the new Voice-SDK to make calls with Twilio. 
I set my backEnd and the connection is fine. I receive the notification in the "To" device and everything runs normal. But when I accept the call in the "To" Device, I cannot connect with my "From" device. It makes the call, the receiver receives the call, but when I accept the call, the Call-Maker continues with the tone. I don´t know if I have to notify something to the call-maker in the `OutGoingCallConnectedListener`. (I´m loging my OutGoingCall getting my `outgoingcall.getState()` and it is `CONNECTED` so everything is fine, but it just doesn't work)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using, including the TwiML? Are there any other logs that could be useful?

Comment: `<Response>
<Dial callerId="+[TwilioNumber]>
<Client>request.To</Client>
</Dial>
</Response>` that is my TwiML. Then, the app code is basically the SampleApp code but refactorized

Comment: @philnash <Response> <Dial callerId="+[TwilioNumber]> <Client>request.To</Client> </Dial> </Response>

Comment: Does the app work as expected before refactoring?

Comment: I didn't build the app before refactoring cause Im using retrofit instead of Ion. The APP works fine, its just I don't know if i need to notify the caller that the call has been accepted. Or maybe it´s a problem from my backend. @philnash

Comment: So what is the code you are using to accept the call on the receiving end?

Comment: ´public void acceptIncomingCall(){
        try{
            Logger.getInstance().createLog(TAG, "IncommingCall Accepted");
            activeIncomingCall.accept(this);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Logger.getInstance().createLog(TAG, "Null IncommingCall");
        }
    }´ Then the listener does nothing. @philnash

Comment: Could you edit you question to add the code? It's kinda hard to read unformatted in a comment.

Comment: suree @philnash

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Thanks for providing some of your code. It is hard to tell exactly what went on in your refactoring, but from what you have supplied it looks as though you aren't passing the event listener to `activeIncomingCall.accept`.

In the original quickstart application, when calling accept you pass an instance of an `IncomingCall.Listener`, unless you've moved your call to `acceptIncomingCall` to within the listener itself, then passing `this` is going to pass the current instance of the `VoiceActivity`.

Take a look at the [quickstart implementation of the `VoiceActivity`](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/voice/quickstart/VoiceActivity.java), particularly the implementation of the [`IncomingCall.Listener`](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/twilio/voice/quickstart/VoiceActivity.java#L215-L234) and compare with your code.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes I pass "this" because I implement the Listener in the class, then, in that listener I don't do anything, as the example code, that only shows a Log.

Comment: It would help to see more of your code then. Can you share the whole class?

Comment: I just edited the question with the classes needed. @philnash

Comment: Ok, the issue is fixed, the problem was that I didn't init the activeIncomingCall in the Listener, thank you for your time @philnash

Comment: Glad it's sorted!